# Browse image inside a tkinter frame

Tags: python, opencv, tkinter

I have a code that includes opening a pop-up window then browsing an image from the directory and i have to place it in an image frame. The problem is i can't fin d a way to place the image in the frame without having the pop-up window opening without pressing the load button or the directory opening without pressing the browse button here is where i am stuck in my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilenames
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


window = tk.Tk()
window.title('Intialization')
window.geometry('350x250')


def browsefunc():
    filename = tk.filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir='initial/directory.. ')
    img = Image.open('%s' % filename)
    image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
    imageFrame = tk.Frame(left_frame, width=200, height=200, bg='grey')
    imageFrame.grid(column=1, row=1, pady=5)
    canvas = tk.Canvas(imageFrame, height=200, width=200)
    canvas.image = image
    canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=image)


def new_window():
    window2 = tk.Toplevel(window)
    window2.title('Pop-Up 1')
    window2.geometry('600x400')
    left_frame = tk.Frame(window2, width=300, height=400)
    left_frame.grid(row=0, column=0)
    right_frame = tk.Frame(window2, width=100, height=400)
    right_frame.grid(row=0, column=1)
    browse_btn = tk.Button(right_frame, text='Browse', command=browsefunc)
    browse_btn.grid(row=0, column=1, pady=5)
    window2.grab_set()


load_btn = tk.Button(window, text="Load", command=new_window)
load_btn.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=tk.CENTER)
window.mainloop()
```

In this code i can't open the image since the left_frame is not defined prior but i posted it to explain my goal. I want my image to browse and open in the left frame without the directory opening before pressing browse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are loading the image in a function in which all variable names are local. There are two things you should do:

1. Pass the `left_frame` object to the `browsefunc()` so it is known within that function:

   ```
   browse_btn = tk.Button(right_frame, text='Browse', command=browsefunc) # change to ->
   browse_btn = tk.Button(right_frame, text='Browse', command=lambda: browsefunc(left_frame))
   ```

And of course you should also take it as an argument: `browsefunc(left_frame)`

2. Second, you forgot to place the canvas on the window after you created it:

   ```
   canvas.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
   ```

Comment: Thank you for your help it seems that is exactly my problem.